# Spring data mongodb DbRef cache

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, dbref

I have a query that fetches 10k documents and every document has a dbref to another document. This query takes ~5 seconds to run and is unacceptable. During debug and logging i've spotted that mongo driver makes a round trip to database for every DbRef.

My DbRef documents are the same for the most part of primary documents. I would like to use a cache for this and don't make additional round trips to mongo for every document.

The question is :  could DbRefs be cached while executing primary query?

Comment: How did you show Dbref round trips in logs? I have been looking for a way to do this for quite some time

Comment: @jemag try to set org.mongodb logging level to debug.

Comment: Actually just finally found it yesterday. It was not implemented before but now it is : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/pull/659 . I can see DBRef fetching/resolution by using the given library version and trace logging : "logging.level.org.springframework.data.mongodb=trace"

Comment: same problem here